# Producing Swagger response model when a part of the response is being dynamically genereated in .NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, swashbuckle

I am using swashbuckle 4.1.

I have a generic response type:

```
{
statuscode:int
message:""
result: dynamically determined wrt request`
count: int`
}
```

Here,
the result parameter is determined dynamically for each endpoint during run-time.

How could I specify the response type to have the respective model for each endpoint for result.

Through declarative statements.

i.e

```
public JsonResult<Response> endpointformodeltypeA(){
---
---
}
```

Its response would be:

```
 {
    statuscode:int
    message:""
    result: modelA
    count: int`
    }
```

`result:modelA`
 is determined dynamically.
How would I define this in swagger through declarative statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it via [Generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/index).

First create your base response class.

```
public class SomeBaseResponse<T>
{
        [JsonProperty("statuscode")]
        public int StatusCode { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("message")]
        public string Message { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("result")]
        public T Result { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("count")]
        public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can respond with this class from your controller action.
Here's an example:

```
public SomeBaseResponse<SomeModel> FirstControllerAction(){
    // It can be anything else than SomeModel

    return new SomeBaseResponse<SomeModel> {
         StatusCode = 10,
         Message = "Success!",
         Result = new SomeModel(),
         Count = 1
    };
}
```

You can create any amount of endpoints with different generic types used.
This also helps to keep your responses generalized and easily parse-able.

Swagger will generate something like this.
(This is not actual representation of the model we created, it's just an example!)
[Click here to view screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hl8D.png)